# How do I stub IQueryable<int> and IQueryable<String>

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, stub

How do I stub these methods:

ProductDAL:

```
    public IQueryable<string> getCatNameList()
    {
        var db = new Database();
        var categoryNames = db.ProductCategories.Select(c => c.Name);
        return categoryNames;
    }

    public IQueryable<int> getCatIdList()
    {
        var db = new Database();
        var categoryID = db.ProductCategories.Select(c => c.Categoryid);
        return categoryID;
    }
```

IProductDAL:

```
    IQueryable<int> getCatIdList();
    IQueryable<string> getCatNameList();
```

Been searching on stackoverflow, but no questions/answers that gets me any closer to understanding how I go about doing this.

Comment: What exactly do you want to create a stub for? The database?

Comment: You need to provide more information, such as when you want to use the stubbed methods. Also, you should do a Google search for a tutorial on unit testing with C#.

Comment: @DerekVanCuyk I changed the IQueryable's to IEnumerable. I'm going to use the stubbed methods in unit testing, but I just don't seem to understand what way I should go about this. Fairly new to all this so yea.

Comment: In this paradigm you would likely have a MockProductDAL for unit testing and have a few hardcoded Categories in a list, and then just go _myCategories.Select(c => c.CategoryId) for your getCatIdList method. Just having a stub method with no real values may not be very useful for unit testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case I would recommend you change your interface to a series of `IEnumerable` rather than `IQueryable`. There is little point having these methods as queryables as they have already been projected.

If you are just trying to stub them, use `Enumerable.Empty<type>().AsQueryable().`

Comment: I changed them to IEnumerable, but how do Istub the categoryNames and categoryID? example would be lovely.

Comment: public IEnumerable<int> getCatIdList() { return Enumerable.Empty<int>(); } would be potential stub if you just want the code to compile

Answer (score 1):

Create and `IEnumerable` of whatever you need to return (can be a `List` or an array). Then convert it to `IQueryable` using `AsQueryable` extension method and pass it to whatever mocking/stubbing library you use.